# GoogleApiClient.isConnected() returns true after calling Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect()

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-plus-signin

Ok, so I'm current implementing Google Drive API connectivity within my app and as a result I have the user sign in through their Google Plus Account. My problem is that `GoogleApiClient.isConnected()` does not always seem to be accurate. The problem is that if I sign in (using the procedure defined in the Android Google Plus documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) and then I attempt to revoke the app's access to the users Google Play account by calling this method:

```
/**
 * Revokes the user access given to application and disconnects from their account
 */
public void onGoogleRevokeAndDisconnect()
{
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        //clear account
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        //revoke and disconnect
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account disconnected succesfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
            //mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();//TODO: Find out why this is necessary to make this not break
            //reconnect
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            //Update button states in SettingsFragment
            mSettingsFragment.updateGoogleButtonVisibility();//no longer signed in
        }

        });

    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must be signed in to revoke access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then when I check the value of `GoogleApiClient.isConnected()` the method returns `true`. Obviously this should return false as the account has been revoked and disconnected. Interestingly enough, when I then try to sign out without signing back in I get an exception saying:

```
01-19 23:14:37.738: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

This is thrown at this method call (`clearDefaultAccount()`) during the sign out process, where the default account is cleared (documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html#clearDefaultAccount(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)), which doesn't say anything about throwing exceptions) Perhaps `GoogleApiClient.isConnected()` and this method check in different ways?

I also know that the account privileges WERE indeed revoked, as when I close the app and reopen it, I'm again prompted to authorize my account. And when I sign out normally, without revoking access, everything works as it should.

**Possible Fix:**
I did find a fix that so far appears to be working - which is to manually disconnect from the googleApiClient using `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();` in the `onResult()` method of `revokeAccessAndDisconnect()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `revokeAccessAndDisconnect()` , instead of using `disconnect()`, since I argue it's still connecting with old data.
Simple code is like:

```
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccount(); 
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
```

Comment: That code does work but that is atualyl what I do in my sign out method, it disconnects the current account - but what it doesn't do is actually revoke the access that the user granted to my app. When they simply sign out they can sign back into the account without reauthorizing, whereas when they revoke and disconnect they revoke all permissions I have related to their account data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make in an AsyncTask and it WORKED.

```
public  class RevokeAccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context mContext;

    public RevokeAccess(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        FragmentDrawer.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        ConnectActivity connectActivity = new ConnectActivity();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, connectActivity).commit();
    }


}
```